# RSpec: How do you implicitly filter tests based on the outcome of a previous test?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I'm iterating through a tree control on a webpage. Clicking on some nodes in the tree will change the content in FRAME_C, clicking on others will not. How do I filter a test to only run when the content has changed? Here's what I'm trying:

```
def viewDifferent? 
    if $prvView != $curView
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end
...
describe "Exercising View" do

it "clicks a node in the tree control" do
    $prvView = $b.frame( :id, 'FRAME_C').document.body.innertext

    Timeout.timeout(50) do
        spn.fire_event('onmouseup')
    end

    $curView = $b.frame( :id, 'FRAME_C').document.body.innertext
end

it "Runs only if the view is different", :if => viewDifferent? do
    puts "Doing some stuff."
end

end
```

My problem is that RSpec is evaluating the filter for all of my tests before executing any of them. In the above example viewDifferent? will always (and does) return false since the two global variables have yet to be set by the previous test.

Is there a way to do what I'm asking? I've been trying to figure this out for days.

Answer (score 1):

A test should always run.  It should setup the state it requires to execute the code path you expect.  It seems to me that executing tests conditionally based on the outcome of other tests totally breaks the spirits of the tests.

You should already know the previous view and the current view are different, and if are not what you expect you have a failure.

Every test should have a very specific path through your code you expect it to execute, and you should fail if it doesn't.  There isn't a way to do what you want because you shouldn't do it that way.

Comment: For unit testing I agree with you. I'm not doing unit testing though. I'm using RSpec to aid in automated, black-box, functional testing on code that isn't mine. It's also not developed in Ruby so that stacks the deck even further against me. There's no way for me to know which nodes will change the view and which ones won't. I've seen the implicit filter used in examples to check if there was network connectivity and then skip if appropriate, I was hoping to leverage that feature for my use as well. If there's no way to do it, then I'll have to engineer my own I suppose.

Comment: I disagree with you, if you want to do a dynamic tests based on the input, for example if a certain value of the input it has to assert a behavior and in other type of input you want to assert other kind of behavior, you have to run tests conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar w/ rspec, but have you tried using a `Proc`? For example...

```
it "Runs only if the view is different", :if => lambda { viewDifferent? } do
  puts "Doing some stuff."
end
```

A symbol as shorthand may even work...

```
it "Runs only if the view is different", :if => :viewDifferent? do
  puts "Doing some stuff."
end
```

As you currently have it, it's calling the `viewDifferent?` method as soon as the test is *declared*. What you really want is to pass a `Proc` so that it gets called when the test is *run*.

Comment: I have tried it with a lambda, never a symbol though. Neither achieve the desired results. the ":if" in RSpec is an implicit filtering mechanism which runs when the tests are described to discern whether or not to run them. I was hoping there was a configuration, or something else I could do to get the same behavior at runtime.

Comment: Sounds like a feature request. Until then, you can always `return unless viewDifferent?`.

Comment: throws `unexpected return`

Comment: @MaicolBen, try `next unless viewDifferent?`.  Using `next` would return from the block.